# Parsing Unbalanced Text into Tables in R

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to pull data from some text files on the SEC's EDGAR webpage and I keep running into a similar problem where there are tables that visually look very simple in the text file, but I have trouble parsing them into something useful in R. In particular, I can't seem to figure out how to balance some of the tables when there are either values missing in a column, especially at the end.

The approach I've taken so far is to read in the text files with readLines and split the strings based on the tab delimiters, but this doesn't always work when there are missing values. Is there a better approach or some way to intelligently coerce each row into a data frame? I can't seem to get rbind.fill to work in this case.

Here is my most recent attempt:

```
raw.data = readLines("http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1349353/0001349353-13-000002.txt")
# parse basic document information
companyName = gsub("\t\tCOMPANY CONFORMED NAME:\t\t\t","",raw.data[grep("\t\tCOMPANY CONFORMED NAME:\t\t\t",raw.data)])
cik = gsub("\t\tCENTRAL INDEX KEY:\t\t\t","",raw.data[grep("\t\tCENTRAL INDEX KEY:\t\t\t",raw.data)])
secfilename = gsub("<FILENAME>","",raw.data[grep("<FILENAME>",raw.data)])

# trim down to table
table13f = raw.data[(grep("<TABLE>",raw.data)+1):(grep("</TABLE>",raw.data)-1)]
table13f = table13f[!grepl("INFORMATION TABLE",table13f, ignore.case=TRUE)]
table13f = table13f[!grepl("VOTING AUTHORITY",table13f, ignore.case=TRUE)]
table13f = table13f[!grepl("NAME OF ISSUER",table13f, ignore.case=TRUE)]
table13f = table13f[nchar(table13f)>0]

# extract data vectors
splittable = strsplit(table13f,"\t")
splittable2 = data.frame(splittable)
```

Thanks in advance for the help and/or advice!

Comment: A link would be useful. From my experience, I can tell most of the time something like this happens, it is a rogue comment char hiding in one of the rows. You can check individual lines to see what is the problem

Comment: @OganM the link is in the first line of code that reads the data, unless I am misunderstanding your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to parse the last `table13f` string using the following line:

```
 data <- read.csv(text=table13f,header = T,quote = "\"", sep = "\t", fill = T)
```

Comment: Ah man, this is great because it actually answers another question I had while I was going through this as well - I had considered just writing it to a text file or csv and reading it back in, but that seemed a waste since I'll need to iterate over many files, which is what your "text  = table13f" does. Since I was trying to avoid the write and then read process, I didn't realize read.csv would be useful to fill it in. Thanks a bunch, this was very helpful!

Comment: Conveniently the SEC does not provide these reports in a standardized format. For most I have been able to tweak the approach you provided, but I'm having trouble with one. The example is this file: raw.data = readLines("http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1386792/0001085146-13-000717.txt"). I've tried using similar code above and tweaking it like this for example: data <- read.table(text=table13f,header = F, fill = T). Any suggestions? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Sorry, I was at a place without R. For me read.csv from above works. The headers may have to be adjusted, though. What's your problem with the import?

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the help. On the second example data I mentioned in the comments the read.csv line runs without error but it does  not parse the data into a table correctly. This is in part because quote = "\"" and sep = "\t" are no longer applicable, rather its fixed width data. I've tried a number of variations, but short of manually counting the width each time and using read.fwf(), I am at a bit of a loss.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice. Too bad that the widths weren't published with the data. I was able to import the data after replacing multiple whitespaces by a tab. I had to use "Tools -> Import Dataset -> From File" however, because read.csv returned an error message I didn't know. Maybe the replacement and import work for you in one step. For replacing whitespaces you should be able to make use of regex.

Comment: Sorry, thought I had responded to his, but thank you that was very helpful!